# pyodbc + MS Access(*.mdb) + UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, ms-access, unicode, pyodbc

I connect to MS Access database (mdb file) via pyodbc.

Some data in this db have polish char like (łóźćśę and so on).
When I fetch some data, polish chars are replaced by strange chars (³, ê).
I try to decode into utf8, cp1250, cp1252, latin1, latin2 but it does't solve my problem (still char are not correct).

Can anyone helps me?

ps. for now my solution is 
`data = data.replace('\xc2\xb3', 'ł')` but it is ugly as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an .mdb file with some sample data in a table named [vocabulary]. When I launch  Access and open the table in Datasheet View it looks like this:

```
ID  word      language  english_equiv
--  --------  --------  -------------
 5  żaglówka  Polish    sailboat
```

The following Python 2.7.5 code

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc

db = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +
    r'DBQ=C:\__tmp\unicodeMdbTest.mdb')

cursor1 = db.execute('SELECT [word] FROM [vocabulary] WHERE [ID]=5')

while 1:
    row = cursor1.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.word
db.close()
```

successfully prints the following in the IDLE shell

```
żaglówka
```

Note the file encoding declaration on the first line of the .py file.